# Changing the Async Pattern in WCF

Tags: wcf

Currently, my WCF service has an operation contract that appears like the following:

```
[OperationContract]
int DoSomething1(int param1, int param2);
```

The publishing references for asynchronous calls to this service operation contract are the following

```
void DoSomething1Async(int param1, int param2)
```

And then a completed event:

```
EventHandler<DoSomething1EventArgs> DoSomething1Completed
```

Is there any way to force this behavior (from my reading, it appears as though this is the "Event-Based Asynchronous Pattern") to publish as the Asynchronous Programming Model (from my understanding, it would be deployed as `IAsyncResult DoSomething1Begin()` and the corresponding `...End()` function)?

Or even possible to implement the more modern async approach with (from my reading/understanding) the Task-Based Asynchronous Pattern (async/await) where the async methods return `Task<TResult>`?

I'm having a hard time getting around the confines of event-based async.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If your client is on a modern platform (i.e., .NET 4.5), then WCF should automatically generate the TAP methods. Otherwise, I believe the normal behavior is to generate APM as well as EAP; is this not what you're seeing?

Comment: Hmm that's interesting. And yes, you are correct, I am *not* seeing APM generated. Is there something I need to do to ensure this? And my client platform is WinPhone8, latest .NET.

Comment: @StephenCleary So looking in the `Reference.cs` file, I see the `IAsyncResult BeginDoSomething()` definition.  But if my service contract is named `SvcContract`, then the class is actually `SvcContractClientChannel`.  I've been instantiating `SvcContractClient` up to this point, looking for those APM methods.  Have I been going about this the wrong way??  **EDIT: Nevermind.  That `*ClientChannel` class is private**.  I think I'm getting a bit confused here.

Comment: The WCF proxy generator (annoyingly) has very different behavior for different clients, and I'm not familiar with all of them. I assumed that APM methods are generated for all (except when TAP is generated), but I could be wrong.